# cross tab/pivoting in pentaho CDE

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I am trying to create a dynamic pivoting in postgresql. my query is including 3 dimensions in which one includes a case statement. and one measure. I have tried various solutions found on web but none is working.
I am looking for a script which converts normal query to a pivoted table. pls help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options, basically:

- write your query in MDX, which can easily return a pivoted table; requires Mondrian schema first;
- use a Kettle datasource and denormalise your data with PDI;
- write a denormalisation function in your postFetch method of the table component: it gets the data coming from the query and manipulates it before passing it to the table renderer.

Code snippet to guide you through the process of denormalising in the postFetch of the component:

```
function(data){
    var resultset = data.resultset;
    var metadata = data.metadata;

    // doStuff - this is the bit you'll have to code according to your needs. The resultset array has 1 element for each row of data; the metadata array holds metadata info such as colName, colType and output index.
    var newResultset = someFunction(resultset);
    var newMetadata = someOtherFunction(metadata);

    // set data to the new values
    data.resultset = newResultset;
    data.metadata = newMetadata;

    // return the modified data object to the component
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I have tried the dynamic pivoting on kettle everyone is showing as statically..Can you please provide me the postFetch script for dynamic pivoting.

Comment: to use denormalisation in Kettle you will probably need to use Metadata injection, so that the number of output fields is dynamic. I'll edit the post to include a skeleton of denormalisation function in javascript, but you'll have to work out the details.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback..my query wold be like " select country, date, sales from tableCountry". I need to Pivot the date field and if user filter the date based on date filter the range will change. The report looks like as attached image. can you please provide the postFetch script for this use case.. PFA https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FjmqvGMgdRSJoc6tQM-zshu_IEfhhDJX